# Typescript: try and check if object has own all of children

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This is my code:

```
type myType = {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  body: string;
}

create(data: myType) {
    try {
      console.log("body:", data.body)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error:", error)
    }
}

create({ test: '1' })
```

Result:

```
body: undefined
```

`test` does not exists in `myType`, so why `try catch` not working?

I want to run my code if `data` have all children of `myType`

Comment: On the last line TS should show a error that `{test:1} is not assignable to myType`. It will in no way prevent you to call it if you really want to. Do you want a function `function isMyType(data: unknown): data is myType` instead?

Comment: `create(dataFromSever)`  this is correct. because this data get from server and i don't know .

Comment: But you need to do a type check on that data as @Dimava wrote.

Comment: then `data` there is `data: unknown` because you don't know what it is

Comment: Do you mind json type checking libraries?